# Como centralizar os dois quadrados inscritos no maior quadrado com CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de deixar os três quadrados do código abaixo, centralizados simetricamente em relação ao centro do maior quadrado  que possui o background preto.

```css
.box{
 height: 100px;
 width:  100px;
 background: pink;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
 
}
 .box2{ 
    height: 200px;
 width:  200px;
 background: red;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
}
 .box3{
    height: 300px;
 width:  300px;
 background: black;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box3">
 <div class="box2">    
        <div class="box">
        </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Também  esta no  **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PenaPintada/n6gw6xba/)** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta setar a propriedade `margin` no CSS dos quadrados internos. Utilizando porcentagem é possível calcular a distância que você quer dar em cada extremidade. No caso de `margin: 10% auto;`, estou dizendo que as margens superior e inferior terão 10% do tamanho da `div` que o contém, e que as margens da direita e da esquerda automaticamente terão o mesmo tamanho.

Vale lembrar que a ordem das margens na propriedade `margin` são: superior, direita, inferior, esquerda. Especificando só um valor todas as margens terão o mesmo tamanho; dois valores as margens serão espelhadas; três e quatro seguem a regra original: superior, direita, inferior, esquerda.

Veja o comportamento no **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7fmsfp5/)** .

Comment: Valeu cara!! Grande ajuda!!